Is it true that $f\cdot \chi_{X_n} \in L^\infty(X)$ if $f\in L^p(X)$ and $\mu(X_n)<\infty$?
Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, i.e., $\exists X_n\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(X_n)<\infty \;\forall n\in\mathbb N$ and $\cup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n=X$.
Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and $f:X\to\mathbb R$, $f\in L^p(X)$ be given.
Since $f\in L^p(X)$ and $\chi_{X_n}\in L^q(X)$, where $\chi_{X_n}$ denotes the characteristic function on $X_n$ and $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 q=1$, Hölder yields $\|f\cdot\chi_{X_n}\|_1\leq\|f\|_p\|\chi_{X_n}\|_q<\infty$, so $f\cdot\chi_{X_n} \in L^1(X)$. But is it also in $L^\infty(X)$ (and why)?

Certainly not. There are 2 ways a function (raised to some power $p$) can be "in danger" of having infinite integral: heavy tails, or heavy spikes (think $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}$ on $\mathbb R$, which has both heavy tail and heavy spike which are not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$). Multiplying by an indicator means the heavy tail problem goes away, but there could still be a heavy spike.
In fact, any spike is too much for $L^\infty$ to handle. One can take $f(x) = \lvert\ln(x)\rvert$ for $0<x<1$ (and $\equiv 0$ elsewhere) on $\mathbb R$, which has an "exponentially skinny spike at $0$" and hence is in every $L^p(\mathbb R)$ for all $p \in [1,\infty)$, is also compactly supported (so multiplying with indicator of finite measure set wouldn't impact it, if the finite measure set contained $(0,1)$), but is not in $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.
